# Different classes made by type with the same name in Python?

Tags: python

I was playing around with metaclasses in Python and found something very curious. I can create two classes with the same name, but that are actually different objects. See:

```
>>> def create_class(**data):
...     return type('MyClass', (object,), data)
... 
>>> A = create_class(x=1, y=2)
>>> B = create_class(x=1, y=2)
>>> A
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>> B
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>> A == B
False
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>> type(b)
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>> type(a) == type(b)
False
```

I thought names within a namespace should be unique. Is it not the case, then?

Comment: Could you explain what 'names within a namespace should be unique' means?

Comment: @User the names of each object in the namespace (in this case, `__main__`), should be unique. I thought `MyClass` was the name of an object, by as explained in the answers below, it is not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Names within a namespace are unique, but that doesn't have any bearing on your situation here.  Basically there are two different things: "names"  and `__name__`s.  A "name" is a variable in a namespace.  A `__name__` is just an attribute of a class whose value is "what the class calls itself".

In your code above, `MyClass` is a `__name__` and `A` and `B` are names.  `MyClass` is not a name in the `__main__` namespace.  The "class `__main__.MyClass`" that you're seeing is just the class's `__name__` attribute, not an actual variable in a namespace.  Normally the class's `__name__` will be equal to the name you define it with, but if you create a class programmatically by calling `type` as you did, it will still have a `__name__` but won't necessarily be accessible via any name in the namespace.

Here's a simple example of the difference:

```
>>> A = type('MyClass', (object,), {})
>>> MyClass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    MyClass
NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

Just passing `MyClass` to `type` doesn't actually create a variable called `MyClass`.  It is these actual variable names that are unique, not a class's internal notion of its name.

A class is the same as another class if they are the same class object.  Even if they have the same `__name__` attribute, they can still be different objects.

Comment: @erickrf: Note the last sentence of first paragraph in the documentation for [**Class definitions**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) where it says "The class name is bound to this class object in the original local namespace". In other words, the executable `class` statement assigns the class object created to an identically named variable in the local namespace. When you create classes by calling `type()` that doesn't happen automatically.

Answer (score 5):

The name of the class is an attribute of the class object itself. Normally when you define a class, you bind it to a variable( with the class name ), but the class name will still be stored inside the class object itself.

And in your case, you are making two new objects which are different, but happen to both be classes, and have the same name. And they are not bound to a variable in the namespace the same way a normal class would be.